# How to install Django+Postgres on Docker using base image Alpine:3.14

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, alpine-linux

**Following are the initial three files that you will need to create in your project folder**

**Dockerfile**

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM alpine:3.14
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN apk update
RUN apk add postgresql-dev
RUN apk add gcc
RUN apk add python3-dev
RUN apk add musl-dev
RUN apk add py3-pip
RUN pip install psycopg2
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.9"
   
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

**requirements.txt**

```
Django>=3.0,<4.0
psycopg2-binary>=2.8
```

**After creating the above 3 files run the following command:**

```
docker-compose run web django-admin startproject example_project .
```

**Next you will have to modify the settings for database in the newly created settings.py file in your django project folder.**
**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

**Run:**

```
docker-compose up
```

**As the server is running go to the Terminal of your container and do migrations**
(Docker Desktop > Container/Apps > Expand docker > Docker_web CLI)

```
python3 manage.py migrate
```

Comment: What's the question or problem you're encountering?  There are some things I'd tweak here (use a prebuilt `python` image; set `CMD` in the Dockerfile; don't overwrite the image's code with `volumes:`; avoid `docker exec`) but this seems like it describes a working setup.

Comment: Thanks for showing concern but this is a self answered question for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick Notes:**
Before proceeding with the Docker installation, I installed WSL using the following documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Then I downloaded the Alpine Linux from the following link:
https://github.com/yuk7/AlpineWSL

Download Link is as follows:
https://github.com/yuk7/AlpineWSL/releases/tag/3.14.0-1

Then I set this Alpine to version 2
You can check the version the images are set to by using `wsl -l -v`
You can set the version to 2 using `wsl --set-version Alpine 2`

**Useful commands:**

1] To rebuild the docker image after making changes to Dockerfile use:

```
docker build .
```